# Как подключить svn на IIS?

Tags: svn, iis-7

Установил visual svn server, создал репозиторий. Он доступен по локальному адресу

https://WIN-3O5FASUK:8443/svn/myrepo/

Как сделать его доступным для моего адреса svn.test.ru или test.ru/svn? Это можно сделать через iis7?

Comment: А чем вам не устраивает адрес `https://svn.mysite.ru:8443/svn/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать VisualSVN Server и свои репозитории доступными по сети или через Internet, то ваши шаги не будут никак отличаться от, например, открытия домашнего сервера с вебсайтом по HTTP(S) или хранилищем доступным по FTP. Никакой IIS вам не нужен. В VisualSVN Server уже встроен веб сервер который открывает доступ к репозиториям по HTTPS.

Зарегистрируйте доменное имя, настройте DNS чтобы он указывал на IP вашего компьютера или сетевого оборудования и настройте port forwarding если это необходимо. Не забудьте про Windows Firewall.

Если вы хотите сделать VisualSVN Server доступным только в локальной сети, то настраивайте DNS.

Т.е. фактически, вопрос можно было бы перефразировать "Как я могу сделать ресурс хранящийся на моём компьютере доступным по сети через HTTP(S) проткол"?.

Учтите, что VisualSVN Server не поддерживает анонимный доступ. Т.е. в любом случае пользователям потребуется вводить username/password, а вам для них надо сделать аккаунт или несколько.

Кстати, можете подумать об установке VisualSVN Server на виртуальную машину в Windows Azure, Amazon EC2 или в аналогичных сервисах.