# Как реализовать контроль версий в проекте из 8 тысяч файлов общим весом под 5 гб?

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий

Имеется проект, у которого 8 тысяч файлов, каждый файл весит не больше 100 Мб. В сумме занимает этот проект 5 Гб. И постоянно нужно весь этот проект перекидывать между двумя людьми.

Как пытались решить эту проблему:

- При попытке закачки на GitHub где то после 75% пишет, что размер чего то там превышен.
- Решили установить SVN сервер. Скачали Visual SVN Server. Запустили, у него имеется в левом фрейме преписка Local. (Нужно ли и как его настроить, что бы к этому серверу могли подключиться с другого города, а не только с локальной сети?)

Может есть другой способ контроля версий?

Comment: Это текстовые файлы, или бинарные?.. Вам нужен именно контроль версий, чтобы просматривать историю изменения файлов, или нужна возможность вернуться к какой-то старой версии файла, то есть бекап и синхронизация?

Comment: @sanmai файлы бинарные. Когда файлы меняется их нужно закачивать на сервер, и если что то не так, откатывать на старую версию файла.

Comment: Тогда вам не Git/Subversion нужны, а rsync для синхронизации и программы для бэкапа типа Borg или ZBackup. Или можно тот же самый [rsync использовать и для бекапа тоже](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/rsync-howto/#part-96878d5592ab495d).

Comment: Смотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525843/8268

Comment: @bahrep то есть устанавливаю эту программу, добавляю репозиторий, создаю пользователя и уже можно ко мне подключаться?

Comment: по имени компьютера работает, по IP нет(

Comment: @helldrg нужно смотреть что у вас там с сетевым оборудованием, firewall, DNS и так далее. В любом случае настройка не будет отличаться от настройки для любого другого сервиса доступного по сети. Проще говоря, настройка +- такая же как если бы вы хотели выставить веб-сайт по HTTP/HTTPS доступным из интернета. Можно, кстати, ещё про VPN подумать.

Comment: я никогда сервисам доступ по сети не организовывал. Веб сайты только локально запускал

Comment: не получается настроить(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Формально* проблему можно решить с помощью Git без использования GitHub или подобных облачных сервисов. Для этого вам нужен любой обычный сервер с доступом по SSH, будь то VPS или физический сервер - не важно. Хоть домашний.

[На сервере один раз настраиваем Git для удалённой работы:](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git/
git init --bare --shared
```

Затем локально, везде, где это нужно, рассказываем Git об этом репозитории:

```
git remote add example user@server.test.ru:project.git
git push example master
```

И так далее, можно пушить-пуллить, всё что угодно.

Но есть проблема. Git и подобные программы не предназначены для работы с бинарными файлами, или просто с большими файлами. Значит Git будет работать не лучшим образом, и потому что бинарные файлы не всегда хорошо поддаются версионированию, *особенно* если это уже сжатые файлы, и потому что вам придётся выкачивать всю-всю историю изменений всех файлов и работать с ней всегда, и со временем вся работа будет медленней и медленней.

Потому для решения вашей проблемы лучше было бы использовать не утилиты для синхронизации текстовых файлов, а утилиты для синхронизации любых файлов. Например, [для синхронизации можно использовать rsync](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/rsync-howto/#part-a86dd46ba87d14e8), а для отката к прошлым версиям любые удобные программы для резервного копирования с функцией дедупликации, вроде [Restic](https://restic.net/), [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [ZBackup](http://zbackup.org/) и подобные.

Comment: блин, заново по другому задам вопрос

Comment: А что скажете насчет Git LFS, может быть он?

Comment: не то к сожалению. У нас самый большой файл 70 мб весит и его закачать надо 1 раз, больше меняться не будет

Comment: Если файлы меняться не будут, тогда тем более вам не нужен контроль версий. Для таких задач есть Dropbox, Яндекс.Диск, и тому подобные программы. Тот же Я.Диск будет стоить вам типа [100 рублей в месяц](https://disk.yandex.ru/tuning), установить, настроить, и забыть.

Comment: как с яндекс диском отслеживать какие файлы изменились? А если понадобилось файл восстановить который был 10 раз изменен и перезаписан?

Comment: Тогда может быть разделите репо на неизменяемые 70мб файлы (хранить на Диске), и изменяемые мелочи (хранить в приватном репо на гитхабе).

Comment: @helldrg так вы пишите что файл "закачать надо 1 раз, больше меняться не будет"

Comment: Ну давайте объясню если не понимаете Git LFS для работы с большими файлами. У нас файлы не особо большие и они не СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО меняться не будут. Но другие файлы которые маленькие меняются постоянно

Comment: Что за беда у вас такаЯ? Арендуете VPS, три команды, и вот вы уже в деле, синхронизируете файлы туда-сюда. Ей богу!