# Как установить и настроить на Windows 8 svn сервер(можно и git) что бы можно было к нему подключаться с другого города по Интернету?

Tags: git, svn, windows-8

Как установить и настроить на Windows 8 svn сервер(можно и git) что бы можно было к нему подключаться с другого города по Интернету.

То есть хочу поставить на домашний пк сервер. Работать он будет когда буду включать пк и сервер на нем. Что бы подключиться к моему серверу, я буду смотреть мой текущий IP, скидывать его человеку который будет подключаться. По этому IP и порту он подключится, либо скинет либо скачет недостающие или измененные файлы.

IP динамический поэтому после переподключения к Интернету он меняется

P.S: из всего этого можно сделать вывод, что люди, которые сервера делают на линуксах не могут сделать его на винде

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий получается. Уточните, у вас именно сервер отдельный есть, или вы на домашний ПК работающий 24/7 хотите это поставить? Статичный внешний IP есть? Также не повредит добавить абзац (или вопрос) в котором вы опишите что вам конкретно надо "пользовательским" языком. А то пока ощущение забивания гвоздей микроскопом ;-) //сама тема хорошая, ловите +1 авансом

Comment: Определитесь, хотите вы всё-таки svn или git, иначе вопрос слишком общий

Comment: хочу хоть что нибудь. Git привычнее мне, svn все таки больше подходит для этой задачи.

Comment: [Более ранний вопрос по этой же проблеме.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1070058/201364)

Comment: Там не раскрыта тема установки и настройки сервера на виндовс

Comment: Тогда вам нужно такой вопрос задавать, а не про Git/SVN, правда?

Comment: Задан вопрос как установить и настроить сервер для контроля версий. Тоесть что сделать и для чего не так ли?

Comment: Сервер для контроля версий настраивается [тремя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1070061/201364) командами, _при условии_ что у вас уже настроен SSH доступ к серверу, проброшены порты, и решены прочие проблемы, специфичные для Windows. Решение этих проблем вы не просили. Наоборот, вы пишите так, что можно понять что проблема подключения по IP у вас уже решена, когда это та проблема, которую вы хотите чтобы вам помогли решить.

Comment: Вообще решение ВСЕХ ваших проблем стоит порядка 100 рублей в месяц, ибо столько стоит VPS с линуксом, на котором всё будет работать сразу из коробки, в три команды. Тут уже вам решать, или 100 рублей заплатить, и получить сразу вещь, которая работает 24/7, или потратить дни и часы на настройку домашнего сервера.

Comment: @sanmai вы привели три команды для настройки гита на сервере, а не сервера для гита. Это разные вещи. Если вы хотите подискутировать на тему формулировки вопроса, а не его решения создайте чат там и пообщаемся, что бы не не мусорить в теме

Comment: а можно на флешку все записывать и доставлять курьером на место. Это будет работать? Будет. Вопрос в том как это сделать именно так. Ответ, который тут дали близок к правде, но пока что сервер ssh не получается запустить

Comment: Для использования гита не нужен никакой специальный и особый сервер "для гита". Достаточно любого с доступом по ssh. У меня нет времени более продолжать эту беседу, в чат переносить нет необходимости.

Comment: любой с доступом по ssh - ответ которого мы заслуживаем

Answer (score 2):

*Git* может работать по протоколу *SSH*.  Например, если имя
пользователя на вашем
компьютере — `user-1`, ваш
*IP*-адрес — `1.2.3.4`, а проект
лежит в директории `C:\Users\user-1\project`, то ваш коллега
должен быть способен склонировать репозиторий командой:

```sh
$ git clone 'ssh://user-1@1.2.3.4/c/users/user-1/project'
```

Разумеется, у вас должен быть поднят *SSH*-сервер.  В интернете
есть достаточно информации о том, как это сделать.

Если в дальнейшем ваш *IP*-адрес меняется на `5.6.7.8`,
коллеге надо будет сделать:

```sh
$ git remote set-url origin 'ssh://user-1@5.6.7.8/c/users/user-1/project'
```

Comment: выглядит неплохо, как сделаю отпишусь, спасибо

Comment: Начал устанавливать OpenSSH. При выполнении команды powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1 вылазит ошибка - The argument 'install-sshlsa.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter

Comment: @helldrg, на официальном сайте git есть подробный учебник, переведенный на русский язык. Читайте главу 4: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B

Comment: @ГерманБорисов там не пишут как сервер установить и настроить, там пишут как обратиться к готовому

Comment: Ссылку `next` нажмите. Подраздел 4.2 Установка Git на сервер

Comment: Крупными буквами заголовок 'Установка Git на сервер', а не установка и настройка сервера. Дальше стал читать, там сервер на линуксе стоит, а нужно на винде